# ¿En que caso se debe usar diferentes Bases de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos

En la empresa actualmente contamos con 3 aplicaciones las cuales realizan funcionalidades total mente diferentes,en algunos casos estas aplicaciones comparten información como (Usuarios, Empresas, Productos etc). Actualmente estas aplicaciones cuentan con bases de datos independientes, y las integraciones se realizan a través de servicios Web, el equipo de soporte ha propuesto tener una sola base de datos para facilitar el proceso de instalación de los tres sistemas, no veo una restricción técnica o razón por la cual no se pueda realiza. La pregunta es ¿Cuando se debe optar por tener bases de datos separadas? Es una buena practica tener una sola base de datos para diferentes sistemas, ¿Que se debe tener en cuenta a la hora de definir esto?

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, lo que preguntas es demasiado amplio y probablemente la pregunta sea cerrada. Las preguntas deben estar formuladas para un problema concreto, de modo que puedas obtener respuestas que lo solucionen. Más info: [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No creo que sea bueno tener en una misma Base de Datos, tablas de diferentes aplicaciones, aunque sólo sea por sentido común.
Luego se me ocurren cosas extrañas que podrían pasar como que realizar una copia de seguridad y una restauración de una Base de Datos para una aplicación, representa que te estaría restaurando los datos de las tres aplicaciones, puesto que comparten la misma Base de Datos.

No comentas el SGBD que estáis utilizando, pero algunos de ellos te permiten realizar consultas entre diferentes Base de Datos, por lo tanto, en tu caso optaría por tener las tablas comunes en una Base de Datos principal (de las tres) y en las otras no, o en su defecto si no es posible, tener una Base de Datos de SISTEMA, y luego una por cada aplicación.

Si necesitas instalar 1 aplicación siempre se instala la de **SISTEMA** y la de la aplicación concreta. Si son 2, la de **SISTEMA** y las dos propias de las aplicaciones.

Comment: Hola Germán, gracias por contestar, pero realmente no es recomendable responder a preguntas que solicitan opiniones, porque el sistema de Stackoverflow en Español pierde calidad. Estoy seguro que todos apreciamos tu opinión, pero te agradeceremos más que contribuyas a garantizar la calidad de los contenidos.